# FactoryGirl has_one and belongs_to not creating the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bdd, factory-bot

I have the following factories:

```
factory :user do
    first_name 'Mister'
    player
end

factory :player do
  rating 20
end
```

When I create a User like this:

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

And I do:

```
puts @user.player.inspect
```

I get:

```
#<Player id: nil, rating:nil, user_id: 44>
```

In the User model I have the following:

```
after_create build_player
```

Which I think is overwriting the player created by the Factory.  If so, how can I solve that??

Notice that the relations are:

```
User has_one Player
Player belongs_to User (foreign key user_id in Player table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do

```
factory :user do
    first_name 'Mister'

    after_create do |user, evaluator|
        user.player = player
    end
end
```

See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do |u|
        u.first_name 'Mister'
        u.player { |p| p.association(:player) }
    end
end
```

Comment: I keep having the same problem...In my User model I have this:   after_create :build_player, and if I get rid of that, the Factory works as expected. But I need that in my model...

Answer (score 0):

Since, user does not need to have (be?) a player, you should have this factory definitions instead:

```
factory :user do
    first_name 'Mister'
end

factory :player do
  rating 20
  user
end
```

When you create a player, it will create a use object and associate the new player object with this user object.